# CSS isn't showing my backgrond. How would I fix this?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying for a while to get my CSS background that hasn't been working all of a sudden for some reason. I've tried following the solutions of other questions related to this one online but these solutions aren't working. I've also tried solving this by using HTML through the `<body background="img.jpg">` tag but this still doesn't work.

[Here is the GitHub repository if you need to look at the file management](https://github.com/TheYellowPolarBear/typb.stream) and the code for the index HTML file and main CSS document are below.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');
* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0);
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  background-image: url(../images/indevbj.JPG);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

div.text {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.social img:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3)
}

.footer {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, .5);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: small;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer p {
  margin: 10px;
}

.footer li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>typb.stream</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
  <link rel='icon' href='images/favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon' />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="text">
    <center>
      <h1 class="header">typb.stream is currently under development</h1>
      <p class="paragraph">Stay tuned for something fantastic!</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    <p>&copy; Copyright TheYellowPolarBear 2019-2020</p>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/theyellowpolarbear">
            <img src="images/youtube.png" width="16" height="16">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.twitter.com/samuel_typb">
            <img src="images/twitter.png" width="16" height="16">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/samuel_typb">
            <img src="images/instagram.png" width="16" height="16">
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have applied **background-color** and **background image** both, Just try to remove **background color**

Answer (score 0):

Since your direct children elements `div.text` and `footer` are in `position: absolute` the whole content of the body is removed from the flow.

Then your `body` element has a computed height equal to `0` and any background applied won't be visible at all.

So you could either apply a background to these children elements, or set a `min-height` to the body itself (or avoid to use `position: absolute`).

*As a side note, avoid to use the deprecated `<center>` tag*

Comment: Are you saying that I would need to remove the `position: absolute` lines from the children elements and the `0` values form the `body` element or change them? Sorry if I'm sounding like an idiot but I'm still relatively new to CSS.

Comment: try by first setting a min-height to the body, as I suggested. Anyway you should know what are the implications of using a non-static position: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/